# How to scrap a lazy loaded website using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, web-scraping

I want to scrap a lazy loaded website using flutter, i used webscraper package as it only scrapes visible elements, how can I scrap all the images and links from the website.

[Please refer the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0RdI.png)

```
class Top2 extends StatefulWidget {
const Top2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
 State<Top2> createState() => _Top2State();
 }

class _Top2State extends State<Top2> {
late List<Map<String, dynamic>> top2Wall;
 bool top2Loaded = false;

void top2Fetch() async {
final top2Scraper = WebScraper('https://mobile.alphacoders.com');

if (await top2Scraper.loadWebPage('/by-category/3?page=1')) {
  top2Wall = top2Scraper.getElement(
      'div.container-masonry > div.item > a > img.img-responsive',
      ['src', 'title']);

  // ignore: avoid_print
  print(top2Wall);
  setState(() {
    top2Loaded = true;
  });
}
  }

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
top2Fetch();
}

@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
return Scaffold(
    body: top2Loaded

        // ignore: sized_box_for_whitespace
        ? Container(
            height: screenSize.height,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              child: Wrap(children: [
                for (int i = 1; i < top2Wall.length; i++)
                  WallCard(src: top2Wall[i]['attributes']['src'])
              ]),
            ),
          )
        : const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.cyanAccent),
          ));
}
  }
```

So basically i want to scrap all the wallpaper available from the website but can only scrap the first 24 wallpapers visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple.
Rest of the wallpapers are fetched dynamic using JS.
Check Pc Browser > Dev Options> Network and scroll down the page you will se something like:
[image]

You can maybe check url where XHR connect and try to scrap it

EDIT
I See page have `pagination` switch so maybe will be easier to use this
[image]

Comment: I mean, yeah I have seen the pagination and I can literally scrap the pagination tab on my app but I want it to have an infinite scroll, but the problem is you need to manually select the page view, and it doesn't appear on the URL address, and about the XHR thing, is there any tutorial link or maybe a brief description so I could understand how to scrap it
ps: thanks for giving your time to answer my question

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the info on further digging I found the link to every wallpaper page 
[https://mobile.alphacoders.com/by-category/10?page=6&quickload=1]
here page = 6  is the wallpaper page, so I'm asking if is there any way to automatically change the page number when a user clicks on a button in my app, so he can be redirected to next page, like the pagination option. I hope you are understanding my question!

Comment: Let say they click `Next Page` then you need to update your fetch address something like
```var pageNum = 1;
String urlToFetch = `your.url?page=$pageNum`
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I figured that thing out, but the problem is the URL gets updated but the new content doesn't shows so do i need to implement '''Navigator.push''' function or something in my onTap ?

Comment: Probably you need to use `setState` or any state managment library

Comment: I have used the setState property but it  doesn't reloads the page or fetches the new wallpaper